# Laravel: Using multiple search terms to get an entry

Tags: php, laravel

Right now, I am grabbing users who fit a certain criteria like this:

```
$searchTerm = 'MULTI';
$multiUser = USER::where('code', 'LIKE', '%'.$searchTerm.'%')->get();
```

Now I changed the code to be "MANY" but we have a lot of users who already have MULTI as their code so I need the searchTerm to grab both.  Can I do this in one query?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```php
User::query()
->where('code', 'LIKE', '%MULTI%')
->orWhere('code', 'LIKE', '%MANY%')
->get();
```